Getting a discrete colorbar in matplotlib + cartopy
I have a csv with 3 columns: latitude, longitude and availability percentage. I want to plot a cortourf map where the colors attend to avilability like this:
Gray 0-90%, blue 90-95%, green 95-98%, yellow 98-99%, red 99-100%
So far I am able to plot the map correctly, but when I try to customize the colorbar, I get this:

So several issues here:

up to 90% availability is grey, that's ok. But then everything gets painted in green, hence ignoring the boundaries
I get the color bar representing up to 105, whereas I have no value over 100 (even forced it just in case).

Here is the code (sorry it is not executable due to the lack of data, but I hope somebody is able to recognise the problem):
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, ListedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Gray 0-90, blue 90-95, green 95-98, yellow 98-99, red 99-100
cmap = ListedColormap(['#bebbbc', '#416ae1', '#7ce494', '#f7f880', '#d77b71'])
bounds =  [0, 90, 95, 98, 99, 100]  
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# Reads data in a dataframe containing columns lat, lon and availability (float between 0 and 100)
data = pd.read_csv(...)

# Create a pivot table to reshape the data into a 2D array
availability_2d = data.pivot(index='lat', columns='lon', values='availability')
lon_2d, lat_2d = np.meshgrid(availability_2d.columns, availability_2d.index)

# Plot the map
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE)
contour = ax.contourf(lon_2d, lat_2d, availability_2d, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-45, 45, 20, 72])
plt.colorbar(contour)
plt.show()


Did you try ax.contourf(..., levels=bounds)?

Found exactly that 5 minutes ago at another answer, so I'm voting for duplicate. Anyway, thank you the same @JohanC
